# How to deactivat the progress of the green bar of Windows ( VISTA)?

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

I use Windows VISTA. When I open the explorer Windows and when I go to a directory which contains many videos, there is in the top of the window a green bar which increases slowly. It sometimes puts one minute so that the green bar finishes its progress. And I have to wait all this time so that my files videos can display in my window (Windows Explorer)

Comment: Shouln't this be on SuperUser?

Answer (score 2):

While that green bar is there, the refresh button to the right of it should have turned into a cancel button.

Answer (score 2):

To disable this, do the following:

Open Organise > Layout > Enable Menu Bar

Menu > Tools > Folder Options > View

Check the option at the top for "Always show icons, never thumbnails".

Hit Apply at the bottom of the window to save this change.
Hit Make All Folders Like This at the top of the window.
Done.